# subscriber pointcloud

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using perception-pcl under ros. I want to get pointcloud from two kinects.
Here, I subscribe to both topics. How can I get the data, which is the "cloud_s" and "cloud_t" into my main function and compute it there?
I tried to put argument on callback function like cloud_cb1(cloud_s) in:

```
ros::Subscriber sub_source = nh1.subscribe("camera1/depth/points", 1,cloud_cb1);
```

but, it did not work.
below is part of my code. Thanks in advanced.

```
...
    void cloud_cb1 (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud_s)
    {
      if ((cloud_s->width * cloud_s->height) == 0)
        return; 
}
void cloud_cb2 (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud_t)
{
      if ((cloud_t->width * cloud_t->height) == 0)
        return;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ros::init (argc, argv, "reg_icp_ros");  //initialize ros  
ros::NodeHandle nh1;
ros::NodeHandle nh2;

while (ros::ok())
  {
//subscribe node
ros::Subscriber sub_source = nh1.subscribe("camera1/depth/points", 1,cloud_cb1);
ros::Subscriber sub_target = nh2.subscribe("camera2/depth/points", 1,cloud_cb2);

...
```

best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10402/subscriber-pointcloud/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have the subscribers outside of the main loop. You only need to subscribe once.
Also you don't need individual NodeHandles, you can use the same handle to subscribe.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-06-28**:
Thanks ffoote, the links were quite helpful.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-27**:
I suggest that you look through the tutorials for roscpp http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Tutorials  In particular this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber on how to subscribe to messages.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-27**:
Once the callback is called you can do whatever you want with the cloud_s and cloud_t. You do need two Subscribers, but one NodeHandle is sufficient.

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks, but still how can I get the "cloud_s" and "cloud_t" in my main function? I just use "cloud_s" and "cloud_t" but it seems to be empty. Btw, I don't get it since I think I need two subscriber for two kinect inputs.